# System.UnauthorizedAccessException cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, sharepoint

Thank you for reaching out to my question. I am developing cordova app with SharePoint. When I'm trying to get or create a list item I get the error `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`. I am stuck here for two days. I do not understand what's wrong.

Error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
error code: 2147024891
Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.
Status:403
Status Text:forbidden.
```

This is the error screenshot:
[image]

My code to create a list item:

```
createList: function(accessTokens,digestValues){


    alert("creating list item");
    var sendItem = {"Title": "Created Title","Age":"27","__metadata": {"type": "SP.Data.WebServiceTestListItem"}};
    alert(digestValues);
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/MyProject/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('WebServiceTest')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(sendItem),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": digestValues,
        "X-HTTP-Method": "PUT",
        "If-Match": "*"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Update Successful");
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert("fail"+msg);
        alert("fail2:"+JSON.stringify(msg));
        $("#userlist").text(JSON.stringify(msg));

    }
});
},
```

Comment: You have right to create a list? How do you set your digest?

Comment: yes I have right to create list. I get digest by making request with `_api/contextinfo` as endpoint with a empty body to my SharePoint site.

Comment: I never use "X-HTTP-Method": "PUT" to add an item, ... can't test atm. maybe leave try this part out and test?
But don't know if that is really the problem :)

Comment: I had tried that but no success.